# (Simple) question about modules and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ and $A$-module; let also $N\subseteq M$ be a submodule. If $I\subseteq A$ is an ideal, and $N\subseteq IM$, then $IM/N$ is a submodule of $M/N$, of the form $I(M/N)$. Now, if I start with an ideal of the form $I(M/N)$, is it said that $N\subseteq IM$? In other words, are the submodules of the form $I(M/N)$ in bijection with those of the form $IM$ containing $N$? I would actually say that they are in bijection with those of the form $IM+N$ (that are not necessarily of the form $JM$ for some ideal $J\subseteq A$). However I saw an argument that seem to use such bijection, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Edit: in the argument that I referred to,  $N$  is itself of the form $JM$ for an ideal  $J$. So maybe the  reason is that the submodules of the form $IM+JM$ are isomorphic to  $(I+J)M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$This is true in the case $N=JM$. I guess the key to making this look more reasonable is that you have

$$I(M/N)=(IM+N)/N=(IM+JM)/N=((I+J)M)/N=(I+J)(M/N)$$

so ideals of the form $I(M/N)$ are the same those of the form $(I+J)(M/N)$ which are in bijection of those of the form $(I+J)M$ (all of which contain $N$) which are the same as those of the form $IM$ containing $N$ (the last two things are the same because when $IM$ contains $N$ you get $IM=IM+N=IM+JM=(I+J)M$).

Here's a counterexample to the general case: take $A=\mathbb Z$, $M=\Z/2\Z\oplus \Z/4\Z$ and $N=\Z/2\Z\oplus\{0\}$. You can see explicitly that there are three submodules of $M$ of the form $IM$, i.e. $0,M$, and $\{0\}\oplus\Z/2\Z=(2)M$, but only two of these contain $N$. On the other hand, $M/N\simeq \Z/4\Z$ which has three submodules of the form $I(M/N)$.